# How can I write SQL code in MS Access that shows multiple transactions by the same customer

Tags: sql, ms-access-2016

I am working on a database of an organ transplant centre. The database is in MS Access.

I would like to write SQL code that shows patients who had more than one transplant organ in a certain period of time. I was successful in writing the code that shows all the transplant operations that was done in range of time but could not write the part that shows more than one transplant/patient.

Would you help?

Here is the code for finding all the transplant ops that were done in the time period:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Transplant Organ Information]
WHERE txdt BETWEEN #01/01/2008# AND #12/31/2013#
```

The column that I have are:

- patient id (PID) "number"
- Type of organ (rorgtype) "category"
- Date of transplant (txdt) "date"

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to write sql code that shows patients who had more than one transplant organ in certain period of time.

I think you just want aggregation and a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT patient_id
FROM [Transplant Organ Information]
WHERE txdt BETWEEN #01/01/2008# AND #12/31/2013#
GROUP BY patient_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your code but it gave me error: cannot group on fields selected with (*)

Comment: @Wess . . . The query written in this answer would not generate such an error.